# The Beginnings of Galois Theory

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking, rhyme

I am a 4 digit number
The sum of my digits is half of me
Add a tail to one of my digit-members
Then the sum of them is three

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am a 4 digit number

> 1811

The sum of my digits is half of me

> 1 + 8 + 1 + 1 = 11 and 11 is laterally half of 18|11

Add a tail to one of my digit-members

> A tall tale is adding a tail to 8 gives &

Then the sum of them is three

> 1&11 is 12 with a digit sum of 3

The Beginnings of Galois Theory

> Évariste Galois 1811 - 1832

Comment: This absolutely much be right and is very ingenious, but I'm 100% unconvinced by the "add a tail" bit. (I don't mean that *you're* wrong, I mean I don't like that element of the puzzle.) Nice puzzle otherwise, though.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Perhaps it's a [rot13](http://www.rot13.com/) svfu tail.

Comment: By this logic even *1181* is also a viable candidate.

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay rot13(Tnybvf jnf abg obea va ryrira uhaqerq rvtugl bar ohg rvtugrra uhaqerq ryrira.) :-).

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan rot13(V'z bcra gb fhttrfgvbaf gb gvtugra hc gung "gnvy" ybtvp - qb lbh unir nal?)

Comment: @swihart No clever suggestions to offer, sorry. Lest there be any doubt, I like this one a lot apart from the tail :-).

Answer (score -1):

Here is a wild, wilder and wildest guess:

> It is a Roman numeral and it is VIII.

As,

> The value of it is 8 and the number of individual digits is 4, which is half of 8.

Also,

> When you add a tail to the last one(I) to make it VIIX(Though stretched a bit), whose value becomes 10 - 7 ( X - VII), though not by an accepted rules, but by lateral thinking...it results in 3.

Comment: Cmiiw, but the sum of your individual digits is not half of the number itself; it's equal instead.